# Answering the question of "WHY" using AI?

Tags: machine-learning, ai, interpretation

We have seen lots of natural occurrences that are happening in the whole world. Since we have great progress in technology and in particular `AI`, How can I employ `ML` to answer the question of `WHY`. In a sense that, without interpreting the result by human, Can machine interpret `why` something is happening or not? Like feeding a machine with lots of input, from synthesized data to actual data, does the machine answer any question or no, it does just analyze the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no, one cannot feed a ML system with massive random heterogeneous data and expect the system to make sense of it by itself.
ML is not magical, it needs to be fed with the right information in order to produce a meaningful and reliable answer.

The closest application to this idea is [Question Answering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) (QA). QA is an NLP task where the system answers a question, but the system must have been trained on a large collection of text and can only answer questions for which the answer exists in the text. For example the system can answer the question "why is the sky blue?" only if the training data contains a sentence such as "blue light's short wavelengths aren't easily absorbed and bounce off the sky, creating a sapphire hue".